# time_ns() result not saved by writedlm() in julia

Tags: julia

I am working with a program which includes many function calls inside a for loop. For short, it is something like this:

```
function something()
....
....
    timer = zeros(NSTEP);
    for it = 1:NSTEP # time steps 

        tic = time_ns();

        Threads.@threads for p in 1:2  # Star parallel of two sigma functions
        Threads.lock(l);
        Threads.unlock(l);
        arg_in_sig[p] = func_sig[p](arg_in_sig[p]);
        end
       .....
       .....
       Threads.@threads for p in 1:2
       Threads.lock(l)
       Threads.unlock(l)
       arg_in_vel[p] = func_vel[p](arg_in_vel[p])
       end

       toc=time_ns();

       timer[i] = toc-tic;

    end # time loop
    writedlm("timer.txt",timer)
    return
end
```

What I am trying to do, is to meassure the time that takes to perform on each loop iteration, saving the result in an output file called "timer.txt". The thing is that it **doesn't** work. 
It saves a file with all zeros on it (except two or three values, which is more confusing).
I made a toy example like:

```
using DelimitedFiles;
function test()
    a=zeros(1000)
    for i=1:1000
        tic = time_ns();
        C = rand(20,20)*rand(20,20);
        toc = time_ns();
        a[i] = toc-tic;
    end
    writedlm("aaa.txt",a);
    return a;
end
```

and these actually works (it saves fine!). Is there something to do with the fact that I am implementing **Threads.@threads**?. What can be happening between writedlm() and time_ns() in my program?

Any help would be much apreciated!

Comment: Are you checking in some way that all threads have finished their tasks successfully before you call writedlm?

Comment: Hi @Bill No, I am not checking any of the task to be completed. I really just assumed they where finished at the point I am calling writedlm... How can I do so?. Thanks!!

Comment: To get a good answer, you may need to revise the question to give a minimal sized working example which runs and shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `it` but try to save by:

```
timer[i] = toc-tic;
```

while it should be

```
timer[it] = toc-tic;
```

Perhaps you have some `i` in global scope and hence the code still works.

Additionally locking the thread and immediately unlocking does not seem to make much sense. Moreover, when you iterate over `p` which happens to be also index of the `Vector` cell where you save the results there is no need to use the locking mechanism at all (unless you are calling some functions that depend on a global state).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code above was typed to be explanatory. In the original code the index is ```ìt```. Regarding the last comment, I think my function are depending on global state, although I am not enterely sure...

Comment: I think that if you need more help you will need to provide a minimal working example that exposes the undesired behavior.